# Laravel: Uploaded Files URL problems with Custom Public Path

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel 5.6 project, I have moved the public folder path from `/public` to `/web` to match the hosting environment. The entire project works fine without any issues.

However, the problem appears when I upload files and try to link them. I have searched all over and cannot find any solutions to this. I have used `php artisan storage:link` to link the storage. I should be able to access files put in the folder by `http://localhost:8000/storage/test.png` but the link comes up with the view provided for the route `/`, not the actual file itself.

It's as if all links to the files are being treated as routes and are showing the default route page instead of the file. I would really appreciate any assistance.

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1nWV.png

Comment: if you create the symlink it should be http://localhost:8000/storage/test.png

Comment: Did you change the settings in [`filesystems.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/filesystems.php)?

Comment: @simonecosci Yes I forgot, that is the URL i'm trying to access. I'll update the post.

Comment: ok, as @Phiter says you should check config/filesystems.php

Comment: @Phiter I tried with and without modifications. Both comes up with the same problem. Perhaps you could point me to a proper instruction on how to set the file up?

Comment: `'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage'`

Comment: @simonecosci thanks. I tried, and cleared artisan cache and composer dump-autoload. I still have the same issue. Here's a a screenshot that should help you understand better: https://i.imgur.com/IPa6JYh.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem.

In the file `core/server.php`, I had this:

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}
```

The `public` part was causing the issue. I set it to `/../web` to match my project's structure and the file linking started immediately afterwards.

Hope this helps someone.

Edit: the `core` directory is where I have moved all the Laravel files. The screenshot in the question has more details.